# How to hide component instead of unmounting it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my routes defined like this:

```
  <Route component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Main}/>
    <Route path="/foo" component={Foo}/>
    <Route path="/bar" component={Bar}/>
  </Route>
```

By default component gets unmounted when you transition from `Foo` to `Bar`. Since I have a computation-heavy code in the component `Foo` (Google Maps with custom animations) I would like to prevent unmount and hide this component instead, so when user goes back it will load instantly.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve your requirement, you can not use two separate routes for `Foo` and `Bar`. You can set only one route for a container component(We name it `FooBar` here) . The `FooBar` combines `Foo` and `Bar`. Use the `state` of `FooBar`  to change the visibility of the two components in the `FooBar`'s `render` function .